# concurrent queries using sqlAlchemy 'scoped_session' raising exception 'This transaction is inactive'

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sqlalchemy

Sorry if this was asked before, but I search all over and couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I'm trying to achieve a very simple task, which is sending queries to postgres DB from multiple threads at the same time.

this is my setup:

```
engine = create_engine(
    f'postgresql://postgres:{password}@{host}:5432/dbname',
    pool_pre_ping=True).connect().execution_options(
    schema_translate_map={None: "my_db"})
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

@contextmanager
def db_session():
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
```

This is what I'm trying to run from each thread(tried using native python Thread and also using  `APScheduler`:

```
def query_build():
    with db_session() as session:
        session.query(Build).filter(Build.number == -1).all()
```

If I'm running the above method from 2 threads or more, I'm constantly receiving the below exception from each thread, while sending commit():

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This transaction is inactive
```

As I read in many places, scoped_session is meant to be thread-safe, but from my experience it simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently, the location of `connect()` is what caused this behavior.
removing the `connect` call solved the problem:

```
engine = create_engine(
    f'postgresql://postgres:{password}@{host}:5432/dbname',
    pool_pre_ping=True).execution_options(
    schema_translate_map={None: "my_db"})
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```